# What's the easiest way to print the address of a member function?

Tags: c++

If I have a base class with a pure-virtual function, and a derived class that implements that function - what's the easiest way I can print out the address that the function actually gets called at?

```
class A { public: virtual void func()=0; }

class B:A { 
    public: 
        void func() { /*implementation*/ }
        void func2() { *** I WANT TO PRINT THE ADDRESS OF func() HERE! *** }
};
```

Also, what's the easiest way to print out the address of a static function in a class, and to print out the address of a global function?

Comment: When you say *fast*, do you mean speed of execution, or short code?

Comment: What do you mean by *fast*? Fast to program, or fast in execution time?

Comment: Doesn't this reduce to "the fastest way to print a constant"?  I mean, If you use `&B::func2`, the address will likely be resolved at compile-time, right?

Comment: Quick syntax for typing :) Not efficiency for execution.

Comment: There's only one syntax for taking the address of a member function, so I'm not sure what this question is about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Edited] As far as I know, there's no way to get the address of the function that *actually* will be called, regardless of virtualness. For virtual methods specifically, the method and destination of virtual dispatch is left to the implementation. However even for normal functions the function pointer may not be the actual code address of the function (although I suspect there are cases where it is).

Comment: Indeed, but every function has an address.  I'm sure `B::func2()` has one too!

Comment: @André Caron: And while it may have an address, the compiler is _not_ required to provide it. It provides a handle: a member pointer. Nothing more. That _might_ be an address. It might not. Technically, function pointers of any kind don't _have_ to be addresses. They could be indices in a lookup table.

Comment: -1 "you should be able to do `std::cout << &funcname << std::endl;`" is meaningless.

Comment: @André: In the case of member function pointers, "address" isn't necessarily equal to "pointer". A member function pointer might just as well be a pointer to a virtual table plus an index into it. Or it might be something else completely.

Comment: @sbi: I'm totally aware of this.  I've already linked to a reference on function pointer implementation in some other comment.  However, OP asked for "the address that the function".  Everyone who answered tried to use function pointers.

Comment: I attempted to clarify my intended meaning here (and my misunderstanding regarding function pointers).

Answer (score 2):

c++ does not give any portable means of printing the address of a virtual function.

Comment: I know member function pointers are [pretty messy](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cpp/FastDelegate.aspx), but why is there no support for this?  Do you mean that there is no support from the standard library or that it's an illegal construct in C++?

Comment: I believe he means that you can only get the addresses of fully qualified functions.  So A::func(), and B::func(), but not just func().

Comment: @Andre: I mean that there is no support from the standard library. If you pass a member function to an iostream then I think it's converted to `bool`... Also there is no portable way to delve into the innards of a member pointer, but it can be done non-portably e.g. for visual c++.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to figure out the option to get your linker to output a link map, and look up the function name there.

Answer (score 0):

A method pointer is not always an address. It is in fact (on gcc) two things:

- An offset
- An address or an index

When the last bit of the member function pointer is 1 the second part is the offset in the *vtable* which indicate the method to call otherwise it is the address of the member function.
The offset is added to the *this* pointer.

That's why a member function pointer is bigger than a common pointer. Also, you should notice that contrary to the function pointer, there is an overhead using member function pointer.