# printing function address using GOOGLE_LOG

Tags: c++, protocol-buffers

I tried to print the function address inside the goggle protocol buffer source. (because there were too many functions named MergePartialFromCodedStream from genereated C++ code by protocc, I wanted to find the function.) but met with an error. The source is below.

```
bool InlineMergeFromCodedStream(io::CodedInputStream* input,
                                MessageLite* message) {
  GOOGLE_LOG(INFO) << "func addr = " << message->MergePartialFromCodedStream;    
              // <-- error line
  if (!message->MergePartialFromCodedStream(input)) return false;
  if (!message->IsInitialized()) {
    GOOGLE_LOG(ERROR) << InitializationErrorMessage("parse", *message);
    return false;
  }
  return true;
}
```

The error message is below :

```
make  all-recursive
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/ckim/Neuro/py-faster-rcnn/protobuf-2.6.1'
Making all in .
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/ckim/Neuro/py-faster-rcnn/protobuf-2.6.1'
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/ckim/Neuro/py-faster-rcnn/protobuf-2.6.1'
Making all in src
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/ckim/Neuro/py-faster-rcnn/protobuf-2.6.1/src'
depbase=`echo google/protobuf/message_lite.lo | sed 's|[^/]*$|.deps/&|;s|\.lo$||'`;\
    /bin/sh ../libtool  --tag=CXX   --mode=compile g++ -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I..    -pthread -Wall -Wwrite-strings -Woverloaded-virtual -Wno-sign-compare -O2 -g -DNDEBUG -MT google/protobuf/message_lite.lo -MD -MP -MF $depbase.Tpo -c -o google/protobuf/message_lite.lo google/protobuf/message_lite.cc &&\
    mv -f $depbase.Tpo $depbase.Plo
libtool: compile:  g++ -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I.. -pthread -Wall -Wwrite-strings -Woverloaded-virtual -Wno-sign-compare -O2 -g -DNDEBUG -MT google/protobuf/message_lite.lo -MD -MP -MF google/protobuf/.deps/message_lite.Tpo -c google/protobuf/message_lite.cc  -fPIC -DPIC -o google/protobuf/.libs/message_lite.o
google/protobuf/message_lite.cc: In function 'bool google::protobuf::<unnamed>::InlineMergeFromCodedStream(google::protobuf::io::CodedInputStream*, google::protobuf::MessageLite*)':
google/protobuf/message_lite.cc:121: error: no match for 'operator<<' in 'google::protobuf::internal::LogMessage((google::protobuf::LogLevel)0u, ((const char*)"google/protobuf/message_lite.cc"), 121).google::protobuf::internal::LogMessage::operator<<(((const char*)"test")) << message->google::protobuf::MessageLite::MergePartialFromCodedStream'
./google/protobuf/stubs/common.h:652: note: candidates are: google::protobuf::internal::LogMessage& google::protobuf::internal::LogMessage::operator<<(const std::string&)
./google/protobuf/stubs/common.h:653: note:                 google::protobuf::internal::LogMessage& google::protobuf::internal::LogMessage::operator<<(const char*)
./google/protobuf/stubs/common.h:654: note:                 google::protobuf::internal::LogMessage& google::protobuf::internal::LogMessage::operator<<(char)
./google/protobuf/stubs/common.h:655: note:                 google::protobuf::internal::LogMessage& google::protobuf::internal::LogMessage::operator<<(int)
./google/protobuf/stubs/common.h:656: note:                 google::protobuf::internal::LogMessage& google::protobuf::internal::LogMessage::operator<<(google::protobuf::uint)
./google/protobuf/stubs/common.h:657: note:                 google::protobuf::internal::LogMessage& google::protobuf::internal::LogMessage::operator<<(long int)
./google/protobuf/stubs/common.h:658: note:                 google::protobuf::internal::LogMessage& google::protobuf::internal::LogMessage::operator<<(long unsigned int)
./google/protobuf/stubs/common.h:659: note:                 google::protobuf::internal::LogMessage& google::protobuf::internal::LogMessage::operator<<(double)
make[2]: *** [google/protobuf/message_lite.lo] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/ckim/Neuro/py-faster-rcnn/protobuf-2.6.1/src'
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/ckim/Neuro/py-faster-rcnn/protobuf-2.6.1'
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

It's complaining `error: no match for 'operator<<' in ..` because I put function address to `<<`. I tried adding `(unsigned int)` cast before function address. Then I got

```
google/protobuf/message_lite.cc: In function 'bool google::protobuf::<unnamed>::InlineMergeFromCodedStream(google::protobuf::io::CodedInputStream*, google::protobuf::MessageLite*)':
google/protobuf/message_lite.cc:121: error: invalid use of member (did you forget the '&' ?)
```

If I put just a number instead of function address, it compiles ok.

GOOGLE_LOG is defined in protobuf-2.6.1/src/google/protobuf/stubs/common.h as below.

```
#define GOOGLE_LOG(LEVEL)                                                 \
  ::google::protobuf::internal::LogFinisher() =                           \
    ::google::protobuf::internal::LogMessage(                             \
      ::google::protobuf::LOGLEVEL_##LEVEL, __FILE__, __LINE__)
```

Comment: You forgot to ask a question. Also, you say things like "*I tried adding (unsigned int) cast before function address*" but don't tell us what happened when you did that, what you expected to happen, or anything like that.

Comment: sorry, I corrected the question. Thanks!

Comment: Did you try casting to "long unsigned int"?

Comment: The usefulness of this information is a mystery to me, as you won't get different values depending on the instance.

Comment: @ChanKim Did you read the message you got? It not only told you what you did wrong but it told you how to fix it. "*error: invalid use of member (did you forget the '&' ?)*"

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7166254/whats-the-easiest-way-to-print-the-address-of-a-member-function

Comment: Is this function a member of a class?  If so, printing it's address may be hard.  A pointer-to-member-function is a much more complex object than a simple address.  (It has to cope with reaching virtual functions in a virtual base class).  Otherwise, I suggest casting to `const void *` and print that.

Comment: Another possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38992236/printing-function-address-using

Comment: @LuchianGrigore I tried that but not work.

Comment: @molbdnilo oh, I think you are right. Do you know how I can tell in what class context the function was called? I have tens of such same name functions found using ctags.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz, yeah, I tried putting '&' but it didn't work.

Comment: @MartinBonner I tried that  but didn't work either. thanks.

Comment: @ChanKim Telling us that something "didn't work" is not helpful. You need to tell us what happened and what you expected to happen.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz, I know, I was into something and couldn't capture it last evening. When I put '&' like `GOOGLE_LOG(INFO) << "test" << &message->MergePartialFromCodedStream;`,  I got google/protobuf/message_lite.cc:121: error: no match for 'operator<<' in 'google::protobuf::internal::LogMessage((google::protobuf::LogLevel)0u, ((const char*)"google/protobuf/message_lite.cc"), 121).google::protobuf::internal::LogMessage::operator<<(((const char*)"test")) << &google::protobuf::MessageLite::MergePartialFromCodedStream'

Comment: @DavidSchwartz I'll put an answer for the error message for putting `&` because I can't paste long texts here.